Can an Injection Reservoir apply to Athletics Maneuvers?
The Injection Reservoir Adjustment allows you to inject a poison into the target on a successful attack.

...Immediately after a successful attack with the adjusted weapon, you can inject the target with the loaded poison...

Many athletics maneuvers are attacks. If I apply the Injection Reservoir to a piercing weapon with the Trip, Grapple, Shove, or Disarm traits, such as a Thorn Whip, can I activate the Injection Reservoir upon succeeding with one of these maneuvers?

Yes
The Injection Reservoir requires that the weapon be one which deals piercing damage, and that the reservoir be activated after a successful Attack. If the description were restricting the item to Strikes only, it would require a "hit", which is short for "Successful strike". Its description does not use any language specific to the Strike action, such as "hit" or "attack roll", nor does it require you to deal damage.
Bottom line: Trip, Grapple, Shove, and Disarm are all attacks, and could potentially allow you to activate the Injection Reservoir, provided your weapon has the corresponding weapon trait, and you've met the Injection Reservoir's other requirements.

(side-note, this assessment also applies to the Weapon Siphon as well)

EDIT:
The requirements for Injury Poison that you successfully strike and deal damage with a piercing or slashing weapon do not apply, because that is describing how to deliver the poison by coating the weapon.  Coating a weapon in poison is a separate, independent delivery vector. You can see it tells you whether the coated poison is lost on a failed strike, which isn't relevant to the injection reservoir. To further illustrate how separate these two are, you can coat a weapon in poison, AND attach an Injection reservoir at the same time, to potentially deliver two doses of poison in a single hit, in the right circumstance.

As I read this, it appears you are suggesting that a successful Trip is sufficient to cause the target to be affected by the Injury Poison within the Injection Reservoir. But I'm unclear on why you think the Injury Poison requirements aren't still applicable.

It's possible this is fully correct way to view the rules for Weapon Siphon, but that should probably be a separate question.

Because Injury Poison's requirements are for delivering the poison by coating the weapon in poison, which is separate from the injection reservoir delivery method.

@Strill: There's nuance here. In terms of delivery vehicle, a piercing attack with a coated weapon or one with a hollowed out piercing weapon (i.e. syringe) will deliver it in much of the same manner. If volume of delivery counts, you can argue that an injection can deliver more poison, but we generally handwave physical volume in favor of assuming that poisons are exactly as potent as their delivery mechanism requires them to be. Given that injury poisons are defined as piercing/slashing, I'd say that the distinction here is between is attack (injection reservoir) vs strike (injury poison).

You can activate it, but it doesn't do anything
Per the series of events described above, you can activate the Injection Reservoir and release the poison as you described.
However, this will likely not achieve the overall goal of causing the target to be affected by an Injury Poison, because you will not have satisfied the requirements for Injury Poisons which states (emphasis mine):

An injury poison is activated by applying it to a weapon or ammunition, and it affects the target of the first Strike made using the poisoned item. If that Strike is a success and deals piercing or slashing damage, the target must attempt a saving throw against the poison. On a failed Strike, the target is unaffected, but the poison remains on the weapon and you can try again. On a critical failure, or if the Strike fails to deal slashing or piercing damage for some other reason, the poison is spent but the target is unaffected.

As indicated above, you can only affect a target with an Injury Poison if you land a Strike that deals either piercing or slashing damage to the target.
The primary purpose of the injection reservoir is to mitigate the other requirements for applying injury poisons to a weapon. Namely, you don't have to use it on the first target that you Strike, nor are you subject to the critical failure consequences.
So ultimately, you'll trip them and then squirt them with an injury poison, but you won't have successfully administered said poison.
As a side note, this answer is based upon the Remaster requirements for injury poisons, but these requirements appear to be unchanged from the Legacy requirements.

Dealing with traits
As described in this answer, items only carry the trait tags that are needed for them. Thus, if an item's features are extremely powerful and warrant the Incapacitate trait, then that will be added to the item unless the feature that warrants that trait isn't just being replicated from another feature that already has the Incapacitate trait. For example, the Wand of Paralytic Shock doesn't have the Incapacitate trait, but it does have a feature which replicates the Paralyze spell and that does have the Incapacitate trait. For comparison, see the Dreaming Round which is an item that has a unique effect that causes unconsciousness and therefore warrants the Incapacitate trait, which is applied directly to the item.
Likewise, the Injection Reservoir doesn't have the Injury trait, just the Adjustment and Alchemical traits. However, in order to utilize the item, you need to load an injury poison and upon doing so, all the traits associated with that specific poison will apply.
So if you use Black Adder Venom with the reservoir, you will need to satisfy the requirements of its traits: Alchemical (just means it won't radiate magic), Consumable (ok, so it's destroyed after being used), Injury (can be applied to a weapon and affects a target with its first successful strike if that strike deals piercing or slashing damage; notably failing to deal piercing or slashing damage incurs the effects of a Critical Failure and causes the poison to be to be lost), and Poison (just means it'll deal poison damage).
The Injection Reservoir states that it allows the character to do exactly one thing:

After a successful attack, you can inject the target with the poison using an Interact Action.

This doesn't change the Injury trait's requirement to deal damage in order to apply the poison, if it did it would say so. The only thing it changes is the requirement that the first enemy hit by the weapon suffers the effect of the poison.
The reservoir does not remove the critical failure criteria, so failing to deal piercing or slashing damage causes the poison to be spent, but the target is unaffected.

That rule is for delivering the poison by coating a weapon. You aren't coating the weapon in this instance, although you could do both at once by coating the injection reservoir weapon. In either case, those are two separate requirements.

Yeah, I would argue the Injection Reservoir adjustment is more specific here and overrides the normal injury poison rule which requires a successful strike.

@ESCE I thought of this answer as I was writing this one (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/212712/31402) and it occurred to me that for the Legacy content, PF2E doesn't seem to require items to carry traits for their underlying effects if those effects already have those tags. For example, the Injection Reservoir doesn't have the Injury trait because the poison you're going to use with it will have that trait. And in order to satisfy that trait's requirements, you need to deal damage.

@Pyrotechnical that's an interesting connection, yeah. I think that should be added to your answer. I don't think that invalidates Strill's answer, but I do find that makes your answer more persuasive.

Is there any reason you're limiting that statement to legacy content? Is it not true in the remastered content?

@brandon it's probably the same for the Remaster, but I hadn't checked. The answer I cite was referring just to Legacy content, so that's what I checked. As indicated in the answer above, though, everything I checked for the first part of the answer was for the Remaster and that matches the Legacy stuff, so it's very likely unchanged.
